# How to automatically download an executable with Selenium and Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver and C# to automate automatically downloading an executable when I click on a link in Firefox. Ideally, I'd like to execute the file as well but for now, I'd like to download it and execute it later. Here's what I have so far:

```
public async void StartDriverFireFox(string proxy)
{ 
    FirefoxDriverService chromeDriverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    var downloadDirectory = @Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\indirilen\\";

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    options.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    options.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadDirectory);
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/jpeg");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/png");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/gif");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-rar-compressed");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "");
    options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    options.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    options.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
    options.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
    options.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
    options.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
    options.SetPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
    options.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
    twitter = new FirefoxDriver(chromeDriverService,options);
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}
```

Can we close the download window completely? The download window now appears in the doc and `docx` files.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to use Selenium to download a file? do you not have a URL for the file so you can download it via `HttpClient`?

Comment: download from facebook. The web client does not allow it to do so.

Comment: This sounds like a security nightmare.

Comment: pass the cookies from selenium to an http client and download with that

Comment: unfortunately i don't know it :(